# Compare lastupdated and createdby dates

Tags: c#

I have two dates: `LastUpdatedOn` and `CreatedBy`. If `LastUpdatedOn` has a value then I want to use that value. Otherwise I should use `CreatedBy`. If neither `LastUpdatedOn` or `Createdby` have a value then use `Date.MinValue`.

In the code below, `CreatedBy` is always used even though `LastUpdatedOn` has a value.

```
var LastUpdated = discrepancy.LastUpdatedOn.HasValue ? discrepancy.CreatedOn.Value.LocalDateTime : DateTime.MinValue;
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var LastUpdated = discrepancy.LastUpdatedOn ?? discrepancy.CreatedOn ?? DateTime.MinValue;
```

or this:

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) with `discrepancy.LastUpdatedOn.HasValue` as your condition. `LastUpdatedOn` is never being assigned to `LastUpdated`.
Your code is the same as this:

```cs
DateTime LastUpdated;
if (discrepancy.LastUpdatedOn.HasValue) 
{
    LastUpdated = discrepancy.CreatedOn.Value.LocalDateTime
} 
else 
{
    LastUpdated = DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description involves two "if"s:

1. If LastUpdatedOn is there
2. If CreatedOn is there

Hence, if you want to use ternary operator, there should be two of them as well:

```
var LastUpdated = discrepancy.LastUpdatedOn.HasValue ? discrepancy.LastUpdatedOn : (discrepancy.CreatedOn.HasValue ? discrepancy.CreatedOn : DateTime.MinValue);
```